# How to get single new line in a Rich Text Box to appear as single-spaced

Tags: c#, wpf, richtextbox

I have a RichTextBox on a WPF window that I am using kind of like console output (output only).  When I add a NewLine as in:

```
rtx_report.AppendText(lclFileInfo.pathOnly + System.Environment.NewLine);
```

it correctly adds just a single new line.  (I know this from copying the text out of the box and pasting it somewhere else.)  However, in the display it shows an additional whitespace row.  So I started browsing the RichTextBox properties, but I am not sure which setting controls this.

It looks like it is just defaulting to double-spaced text, but I do not see anything that controls this.  Can anyone explain how to get it to be single-spaced or otherwise not show that extra line?

TIA,

Paul

== Edit ==

P.S. More info as requested by HatSoft

The string content of lclFileInfo.pathOnly is
C:\Users\Paul\Documents\Roadway

However, the same problem happens on all of these lines of code:

```
rtx_report.AppendText("File Changed:" + System.Environment.NewLine);
rtx_report.AppendText(lclFileInfo.pathOnly + System.Environment.NewLine);
if (lclFileInfo.isDirectory == false)
        rtx_report.AppendText(lclFileInfo.fileNameOnly + System.Environment.NewLine);
rtx_report.AppendText("Changed On: " + lclFileInfo.currentTimestamp + System.Environment.NewLine);
```

Comment: Can you please copy/paste the string from lclFileInfo.pathOnly for further investigation

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try this

```
rtx_report.AppendText(lclFileInfo.pathOnly + "\r");
```

Comment: This solution is only visual. If you copy/paste the text into Word for example. All the lines will be concatenated without any line break.
I my code, I'm using Environment.NewLine and not "\r"
And also the solution  from @Yougjae.

Answer (score 6):

In Xaml, set `RichTextBox` Paragraph property margin to zero.
By setting to `0` will not add additional line spacing.

```
<RichTextBox AcceptsReturn="True">
    <RichTextBox.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Paragraph}">
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0" />
        </Style>
    </RichTextBox.Resources>
</RichTextBox>
```